# .Net Rsa decrypt using x509 certificate

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, x509certificate

I have certificate with private key(.pfx) and exported public key(.pem).
I can encrypt string using private key, but has trouble decrypting it with public. 
Every time i get "Key doesn\t exist".
Here i try to get public key  - its not null.

```
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2("sem-cert-public.pem");
string a= cert.GetPublicKeyString();
```

But decrypting by that way is not working.

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
                    int keySize = rsa.KeySize;
                    int base64BlockSize = ((keySize / 8) % 3 != 0) ? (((keySize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((keySize / 8) / 3) * 4;
                    int iterations = inputString.Length / base64BlockSize;
                    var arrayList = new ArrayList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
                    {
                        byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(
                            inputString.Substring(base64BlockSize * i, base64BlockSize));

//crashes here
                        arrayList.AddRange(rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false));
                    }
```

Dont know where is the trouble. Im sure public key exists.

Comment: You need the public key for encryption and the private key for decryption. If you want to send a trusted and encrypted message from A to B, then sign with private A and encrypt with public B. B can proof the sign with public A and decrypt with private B.

Comment: Yeah. But the problem is: i get en error decrypting (encrypting to btw) with public. Although PK exists.

Comment: @TooLazy you cannot decrypt with the public key. It's saying "key doesn't exist" because it is looking for the *private* key.

Comment: But when im trying to verify signature with the same PK i have no trouble.
`signedXml.CheckSignature(public_cert)`
I mean, what if i need the keys to be separated.

Comment: signatures are created by using private key and validated by using public key. Data encryption is performed by using public key and data decryption by using private key. And remember that if you encrypt seomething with public key, it cannot be used to decrypt this data.

Comment: Being able to decrypt with a public key would defeat the entire purpose of encryption, don't you think?

Comment: No, because decryption with public key is used in digital signature validation process. Digital signature provide data authentication (integrity) means, not privacy.

Comment: So is there any way to encrypt using private key and decrypt using public?
I mean any code sample or smth that would help me.

Comment: As I said, this type of encryption (encryption with private key and decryption with public key) is called digital signature and it is not intended to provide data privacy.

Comment: Last try with a real world example: There is a door and two kind of keys for that door. One key is to **lock** the door (lets call it the *public key*) and the other can **unlock** the door (lets call it the *private key*). Now you ask us, how to **unlock** the door with the **public key**! The only ways are lockpicking, breaking the door (brute force) or stealing the private key.

Comment: During the digital signing process, a content is hashed and then ENCRYPTED using the PRIVATE KEY. During the signature verification process, the signature is DECRYPTED using the PUBLIC KEY. The perfect mathematics of RSA allows encryption/decryption by both keys. THEREFORE, decryption with the public key or encryption with the private key is valid, it is just that, this must only be used for signing and signature verification. I don't know what you trying to achieve, but, you can check the [BouncyCastle Project C# Port](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)